# Selenium giving different results

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a bit of an issue using Selenium with python. There is a page I'm scraping, and I'm accessing a children of a parent element. However each time I run the script, it's not always guaranteed that I'll be able to get the children.

So for example, I have:

```
filters = driver.find_element_by_class_name("classname")

filters_children = filters.find_elements_by_class_name("anotherclassname")
```

And I print out filters_children[1] just to make sure.

Around 60% it will work fine, and filters_children will have a list of the children elements. However the other 40%, it'll have a NoneType so it won't be able to grab the elements.

I tried using a sleep of up to 10 seconds after the page rendered but that hasn't helped a whole lot.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the element by jspath or xpath, and did that give you the same results?

Comment: I have not tried that Mike, I'll try that out thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent class might be too broad and some time you might get a different element, then your second query will fail to find the proper child.

When searching via css selector, you can combine multiple nested class by using spaces between them. You could then combine your nested query into one.

Also I suggest that you use wait until in this case to ensure that the element will be present. Compare to sleep, this will send the request periodically to the page until it finds your request.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, '30')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located("css selector", ".classname .anotherclassname")))
```

If the element also need to be visible, change ***presence_of_all_elements_located*** to ***visibility_of_any_elements_located***